# How to resolve stable_diffusion.openvino dependency conflict with numpy?

Tags: python, build, dependencies, blender, stable-diffusion

I'm trying to install [stable_diffusion.openvino](https://github.com/bes-dev/stable_diffusion.openvino) to get Stable Diffusion working on an Intel Mac, and with a Blender addon.

But at the step of `pip install -r requirements.txt`, I encounter this error:

> ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 2) and numpy==1.19.5
> because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
>
> The conflict is caused by:
> The user requested numpy==1.19.5
> opencv-python 4.5.5.64 depends on numpy>=1.21.2; python_version >= "3.10"
>
> To fix this you could try to:
>
> 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
> 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
>
> ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit
> https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts

"Resolution impossible?" Doesn't sound good. And yet, that page offers some suggestions. I'm just not knowledgeable enough to know which course of action to take. Even getting this far was a long journey with many hurdles. I'm using [pyenv](https://fathomtech.io/blog/python-environments-with-pyenv-and-vitualenv/) and the extension [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv).

Here are the contents of requirements.txt:

- `numpy==1.19.5`
- `opencv-python==4.5.5.64`
- `transformers==4.16.2`
- `diffusers==0.2.4`
- `tqdm==4.64.0`
- `openvino==2022.3.0`
- `huggingface_hub==0.9.0`
- `scipy==1.9.0`
- `streamlit==1.12.0`
- `watchdog==2.1.9`
- `ftfy==6.1.1`
- `streamlit_drawable_canvas==0.9.1`
- `pillow==9.0.1`
- `piexif==1.1.3`

If I go with "remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict", what dp the steps for that look like? Do I edit `requirements.txt` to point to a different numpy version and try again? I don't know how to find the compromise - a version of numpy that satisfies al the requirements (if there is one).

If none of this works, I'm open to trying an [OpenVINO Notebook](https://medium.com/openvino-toolkit/how-to-run-stable-diffusion-on-intel-gpus-with-openvino-840714f122b4) as long as it can work with either:

- the [AI-render Blender addon](https://github.com/benrugg/AI-Render) or
- the [stability.ai Blender addon](https://github.com/Stability-AI/stability-blender-addon-public/releases/)

Not sure if OpenVINO Notebooks can be used this way, but my guess is no.

I need to get this installed locally, because rendering in the cloud would be pricey, and unnecessary. I'm sure it's possible to get this working for Intel Macs ([DiffusionBee](https://diffusionbee.com/) did it, but that app presently only supports stills, not animated frames). Any help would be much appreciated.